# How to find scroll top value for div

Tags: html, video, scrolltop

I am working on responsive site. We need when a user see video section that's need to autoplay. If set scroll top for video tag is not working. But i set scrolltop to window it's working fine.

```
<video id="test">
</video>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(window).scroll(function () {
      var js=$('#test-28').scrollTop();
        console.log(js);
      });
   });
</script>
```

Its always show 0

Anyone know how to slove this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `offest().top` to get distance to reach `video` element. `scrollTop` will get `window scroll` distance not distance to an element.  Just use this:

```
$('#test').offset().top
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zc90eukg/1/)**

```
   $(window).scroll(function () {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
       var scrollToVid = $('#test').offset().top
        console.log(scrollTop);
        console.log(scrollToVid);

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= scrollToVid) {
        alert('You reached to the video!');
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

`document.body.scrollTop + Element.getBoundingClientRect().top`

1. `document.body.scrollTop` is the offset of document had scrolled out viewport
2. `Element.getBoundingClientRect().top` is the offset of element to viewport top.