# Having the same nav bar become fixed after scrolling past a certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a nav bar within my header that I would like to become fixed after the user scrolls past a certain element. I would also like to achieve the same animation effect as seen at http://pixelmatters.com

When I say 'same' I mean using the same nav bar/header element that I'm using at the top, rather than using a duplicate somewhere else in my document.

I've tried to achieve he result with my own code shown below. I've also included a jsFiddle link of my current setup.

**jQuery**

```
var bottomElement = $('.dividerWrap').offset().top + $('.dividerWrap').height();

$(window).on('scoll', function() {
  var stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());

  if (stop > bottomElement) {
    $('.header').addClass('isFixed');
  } else {
    $('.header').removeClass('isFixed');
  }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/npfc8wsx/1/

Comment: there is a typo in your code `$(window).on('scoll', function() {` missing r in scroll

Comment: Ahh yes, wow. Can't believe I missed that. It's the darndest things sometimes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered something like that few days ago. please take a look at this code:

```
   $(window).scroll(function () {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
       var scrollToVid = $('#test').offset().top
        console.log(scrollTop); //see window scroll distance //
        console.log(scrollToVid); //see scroll to div offest//

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= scrollToVid) {
        alert('You reached to the video!');
        }
      });
```

**[jSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zc90eukg/1/)**

**[Main Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029058/how-to-find-scroll-top-value-for-div/36029366#36029366)**

now for you some code must change:

```
   $(window).scroll(function () {
       var scrollToElem = $('.dividerWrap').offset().top

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= scrollToElem) {
        $('.header').addClass('isFixed');
        } else {
        $('.header').removeClass('isFixed');
        }
      });
```

Comment: Awesome! I've got it to work in my example above after correcting a typo. Question: Since this is adding a class to an element, can I add transitions to that class that's being added to accomplish the bar transitioning down? Can it be that simple?